# lucene index getDocCount() does not return the same value as total input document number

Tags: java, lucene

I have 1.2M lines to be indexed, each line is read as a document in the lucene index writer. After the index has been built, I try to assert the total number o f records that have been indexed. This number is less than 1.2M.

Details for adding the files is in the following way:

```
    Directory fsDir = FSDirectory.open(this.indexLoc, NoLockFactory.INSTANCE);
    IndexWriterConfig iwConf = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    iwConf.setOpenMode(mode);
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(fsDir, iwConf);
    int count=0;
    FileInputStream input;
    input = new FileInputStream(new File(String.valueOf(dir)));
    CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input,decoder);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        Document d = new Document();
        d.add(new TextField(this.fieldName, line, Store.NO));
        indexWriter.addDocument(d);
        count++;
    }

    indexWriter.commit();
    indexWriter.close();
    reader.close();
    isr.close();
    input.close();
}
```

The way I get the index docs number is as below:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(this.indexLoc));
int docNum = reader.getDocCount(this.fieldName);
```

I traced the that 1.2M has been added to document d. However, why is variable docNum value less than 1.2M?

When I test with small size document, say 1k, the two numbers are consistent.

p.s., I'm using lucene 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexReader.getDocCount(String field)` will return the number of documents that have **at least one term** for this field. So if the `line` is empty, the document count will not increase by `addDocument`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've added a statement to check if line is empty, which returns false. Since it has included an analyzer with stopwords, will it be possible that the line is transformed to empty terms after the analyzer so that the doc count is not increased? @locoyou

Comment: @HappyCoding yes, you are right. `d` may be empty if you use analyzer.